# when using props in styled component it works well but shows warning (Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `cen` )

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, styled-components

**Warning: Received "true" for a non-boolean attribute "cen" If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: cen="true" or cen={value.toString()}.** When i using Props in Styled-Component with typescript and Material-UI it works well but shows warning

```
import React from 'react'  
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';

interface Cnt {
  cen?: boolean
}
const Bnt3 = styled(Button)`
&&{
  ${(props:Cnt) => props.cen && 'display: block;'}
  margin: 30px auto;
  border-radius: 24px;
  padding: 8px 28px;
}
`
const Test: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <>
    <Bnt3 cen variant="contained" type="button" color="secondary" >Log In</Bnt3>
    <Bnt3 variant="contained" type="button" color="secondary">Log In</Bnt3>
    </>
  ); 
}
export default Test;
```

[image]

Comment: Which version of `styled-components` are you using? This is not reproducible in `4.3.2`.

Comment: these are the versions -- styled-components: ^4.3.2,  @types/styled-components: ^4.1.18, react: ^16.8.6, react-dom: ^16.8.6, typescript: 3.5.3,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a kind of data type error.! so i try to fix with string type instead of Boolean.

```
import React from 'react'  
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';

interface Cnt {
  cen?: string
}
const Bnt3 = styled(Button)`
&&{
  ${(props:Cnt) => props.cen && 'display: block;'}
  margin: 30px auto;
  border-radius: 24px;
  padding: 8px 28px;
}`

const Test: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <>
    <Bnt3 cen='true' variant="contained" type="button" color="secondary" >Log In</Bnt3>
    <Bnt3 variant="contained" type="button" color="secondary">Log In</Bnt3>
    </>
  ); 
}
export default Test;
```

Comment: A problem with this solution is that it will consider any non-empty string as truthy, including `'false'`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a demo of the exact code that you have shared: [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-styled-components-warning)

It doesn't show any warning. Is there anything else that might be missing from the code that you've shared?

In general though, here is why you get such a warning: [HTML Attribute Warning](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/faqs#why-am-i-getting-html-attribute-warnings)

> If you're seeing this warning you are probably passing true where
>   "true" would be appropriate. It's likely that this comes from a .attrs
>   property, or from a completely unrelated prop that you're passing to a
>   styled(Component) component.

#### UPDATE:

Unfortunately it is `@material-ui/core` that is passing all the props which it cannot recognize down to html. Since `cen` is unrecognized, it gets passed down to html and only string value can be flushed to html. Hence the error. You can either use "true" or "false" as string like the error suggests or another way would be to separate your custom props from the rest of the props by using `styled-components`'s css prop. Rewrite the component in this manner:

```
const StyledButton = ({ cen, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <Button
      css={`
        && {
            ${cen && 'display: block;'}
            margin: 30px auto;
            border-radius: 24px;
            padding: 8px 28px;
          }
      `}
      {...props}
    />
  )
}
```

This way you can stop your custom props from propagating down the tree.

Here's a couple of official posts to check if you're not aware of how to setup `css` prop in `styled-components`.

- [Manual setup](https://medium.com/styled-components/announcing-native-support-for-the-css-prop-in-styled-components-245ca5252feb)
- [For create-react-app](https://medium.com/styled-components/css-prop-support-for-create-react-app-37e8c5d96861)

Comment: Your Link is Useful and i missed some code from my error (sorry about that) here i again update my question. Please check it.!

Comment: Updated the answer. Have a look.

Comment: thank you for your share! i used typescript with react. so still i could not used your code. anyhow i find another way to fix that error.!

Comment: Using string is what I mentioned as well, as one of two ways — _You can either use "true" or "false" as string like the error suggests_. Good that you were able to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to convert the boolean to string like:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';

export const TableRowWithOpacity = styled(TableRow)<{ completed: string 
}>`
  && {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: ${(props) => (props.completed === 'true' ? 0.5 : 1)};
 }
`;
```

using it like:

```
<TableRowWithOpacity completed={completed.toString()}>...</TableRowWithOpacity>
```